# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'take' with Dask

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dask

I have an issue with Dask.
I have checked the csv file and everything is OK, I do not upload it because it is confidential. But maybe you can try your own CSV and see that you get the same error.

My code is bellow:

````
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(n_workers=4)
client

import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('merged_data.csv')

X=df[['Mp10','Mp10_cal','Mp2_5','Mp2_5_cal','Humedad','Temperatura']]

y = df['Sector']

from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

import joblib
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Create the parameter grid based on the results of random search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 1000]
}
# Create a based model
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# Instantiate the grid search model
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 5, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train).compute()```
````

Bellow the error:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 288 candidates, totalling 1440 fits

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17712/1827769193.py in <module>
----> 1 grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train).compute()

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    889                 return results
    890 
--> 891             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    892 
    893             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1390     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1391         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1392         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1393 
   1394 

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    836                     )
    837 
--> 838                 out = parallel(
    839                     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    840                         clone(base_estimator),

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1054 
   1055             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1056                 self.retrieve()
   1057             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1058             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    933             try:
    934                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 935                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    936                 else:
    937                     self._output.extend(job.get())

C:\WORKSPACE\DataLab\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    443                     raise CancelledError()
    444                 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 445                     return self.__get_result()
    446                 else:
    447                     raise TimeoutError()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    388         if self._exception:
    389             try:
--> 390                 raise self._exception
    391             finally:
    392                 # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'take'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that "*maybe you can try your own CSV and see that you get the same error*" is **not** how it works - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Yes, a reproducible example will help. For dask-ml, you can use `dask_ml.datasets.make_classification` to create a synthetic dataset for this question.

Answer (score 6):

X, y are Dask DataFrames, and I believe you need to use Dask Arrays for GridSearchCV.

To convert your Dask DataFrames to Dask Arrays, you can use:

```
X = df[['Mp10','Mp10_cal','Mp2_5','Mp2_5_cal','Humedad','Temperatura']].to_dask_array(lengths=True)
y = df['Sector'].to_dask_array(lengths=True)
```

The rest of your code should work after this.

Also, you don't need call `compute()` with `grid_search.fit` :)

Comment: I work perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete the answer : the take() method is implemented for Bags and Dask Arrays but not for Dask Dataframes. This is why you need to turn your Dask DataFrame into a Dask Array